# What steps should I take to resolve error "System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added."

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

In one of my Delphi XE2 environments, I get this error:

```
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
```

It *only* happens when I try the refactoring "Find Unit" (for the identifier currently under the code editor cursor).

What steps should I take to investigate this deeper?

Delphi XE2 on a Windows 8 x64 system that has both Delphi XE1, XE2 and a truckload of 3rd party components installed.

No Visual Studio installed however (and right now, not enough disk space for it either)

Comment: IDE bugs somewhat tricky to fix.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know. That's why I ask for some guidance (:

Comment: My advice is to use a different tool